# Bike routing suggestions in iOS maps - which API?

Tags: ios, maps

Which is the best solution for getting bike routes for iOS application?

Comment: What have you tried?  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: openstreetmaps, mapquest API, I wonder if there is a better solution that OSM. That link talks about bike maps?

Comment: You should edit that information into your question, because that helps people answer you. You should explain what you liked and didn't like about each, and what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps offers bike routes in many cities. I think it is a really good option.